# Change shell within Perl script

Tags: perl, shell, unix

I am looking for a nice way to get the following done:

So I have a script that I need to run in Python in Unix by calling from a Perl script that was, in turn, called from my Excel VBA macro in Windows using Plink. The Python script, due to dependency issues, has to run in either csh or bash, and I will need to use export/setenv to add a few libraries before running the script. However by default, perl runs in sh shell and as such, there is no way I can add in all the dependencies and have the Python script to run.

So, I am just wondering if there is EITHER: 1. a way for me to add dependencies to sh shell in the perl script, OR 2. force my perl script to run in csh (preferred, since for some reason .bashrc for the account runs into permission issues).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: "The Python script, due to dependency issues, has to run in either csh or bash" Yeah, no. That sounds suspect. Add more details.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: put it simply, if I run it in sh, the .cshrc does not gets loaded and I need a few export PATH= or setenv PATH= there.

Answer (score 2):

How about "3. Set the appropriate environment variable in the Perl or Python scripts"?

```
$ENV{'PATH'} = ...
```

...

```
os.environ['PATH'] = os.pathsep.join(newpaths + os.environ['PATH'].split(os.pathsep))
```

(dunno how to get the path separator in Perl, sorz)

Comment: I can not vote up yet but this does sounds like a reasonable approach, do I have to define $ENV first by calling my $ENV or Perl should be able to recognize it automatically? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't know enough about Perl to be able to answer that, but it would make sense for it to be a global object.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll give it a try and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

To force the shell to `csh`, try the following in Perl :

```
`/bin/csh -c "command_name"`;
```

**Edit**:

You can use ENV variable, like this. Try that :

```
$s = `/bin/bash -c 'VAR_FOO=753; echo \$VAR_FOO'`;
print $s;
```

Comment: Tried that but for some reason if I do "echo $SHELL" in the command_name I still ended up with /bin/sh.....

Comment: See my edited post, try that and tell me if it's working or not

Comment: I'll give it a shot when I get to work tomorrow morning (no VPN token unfortunately), thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just change the .cshrc script, apparently the addition to PATH, for some reason, did not work for me. After that, everything runs smoothly by putting all into one line

so basically it looks something like this

```
/path/to/.cshrc && /python/path/to/python
```

Hope that helps!